# How to delete a collection with all its sub-collections and documents from Cloud Firestore

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a Collection in Cloud Firestore and it has millions of documents and sub-collections. I want to delete this collection with all its documents and sub-collection. We can do this from Firebase console but that will take ages to delete this collection.

Is there any firebase cli command or node.js code snippet by using I can delete this collection?

Answer (score 1):

You can delete a collection by deleting all its documents. You can read more in the [official docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data#collections). Example code here:

```
async function deleteCollection(db, collectionPath, batchSize) {
  const collectionRef = db.collection(collectionPath);
  const query = collectionRef.orderBy('__name__').limit(batchSize);

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    deleteQueryBatch(db, query, resolve).catch(reject);
  });
}

async function deleteQueryBatch(db, query, resolve) {
  const snapshot = await query.get();

  const batchSize = snapshot.size;
  if (batchSize === 0) {
    // When there are no documents left, we are done
    resolve();
    return;
  }

  // Delete documents in a batch
  const batch = db.batch();
  snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
    batch.delete(doc.ref);
  });
  await batch.commit();

  // Recurse on the next process tick, to avoid
  // exploding the stack.
  process.nextTick(() => {
    deleteQueryBatch(db, query, resolve);
  });
}
```

In case the answer above is not working, you can use Cloud Functions as in [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/delete-collections)

Comment: Where should I run this above code? Should I put this in javascript file and run it? Can you give me a slight idea about that?

Comment: you can run this in a node.js server. If you don't want to do that, then going with the CLI approach as in the link I provided above is your best choice

Answer (score 1):

The Firebase CLI has a `firestore:delete` command that recursively deletes content too. See its documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#firestore-commands).

Note that neither the API nor the CLI are likely to be significantly faster than the console. Since there is no API to bulk-delete data, they all are essentially taking the same approach.